# C++ tic tac toe game only wins with one combination

Tags: c++

I want the program to print "You win" when any of the instances in the champion() function are given. It only shows a winner when "123" is inputted. Whenever three X's are displayed anywhere else the program continues. For instance if three X's are given diagonally the program will still continue. Novice programmer so any criticism is greatly appreciated.

```
class TicTacToe {
 private:
  char map[GRID_SIZE][GRID_SIZE];

 public:
  void computers_turn() {
    while (true) {
      int choice = (rand() % 9) + 1;

      int row = choice / 3;
      int col = choice % 3;
      char grid_position = map[row][col];

      if (grid_position == 'X' || grid_position == 'O') {
        std::cout << "Space taken. Try again" << std::endl;
      } else {
        map[row][col] = (char)'O';
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  void champion() {
    const char* possiblities[8] = {"123", "456", "789", "147",
                                   "258", "369", "159", "753"};

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      char previous_pos = '0';
      bool winner = true;
      const char* possible_moves = possiblities[i];

      for (int index = 0; index < GRID_SIZE; index++) {
        char character = possible_moves[i];
        int entered_num = character - '0';
        int grid_space = entered_num - '1';

        int row = index / GRID_SIZE;
        int col = index % GRID_SIZE;

        char grid_coordinate = map[row][col];

        if (previous_pos == '0') {
          previous_pos = grid_coordinate;
        } else if (previous_pos == grid_coordinate) {
          continue;
        } else {
          winner = false;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (winner) {
        puts("You win");
        exit(0);
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  void playgame() {
    std::string input;

    while (true) {
      std::cout << "Go player one" << std::endl;
      getline(std::cin, input);
      if (input != " ") {
        char entered = input.c_str()[0];

        if (entered >= '1' && entered <= '9') {
          int entered_num = entered - '0';
          int index = entered_num - 1;
          int row = index / 3;
          int col = index % 3;
          char grid_position = map[row][col];

          if (grid_position == 'X' || grid_position == 'O') {
            std::cout << "Space taken. Try again" << std::endl;
          } else {
            map[row][col] = (char)'X';
            break;
          }
        } else {
          std::cout << "Only numbers 1 - 9" << std::endl;
        }
      } else {
        std::cout << "Have to enter something, try again" << std::endl;
      }
    }
  }

  void generateGrid() {
    int number = 1;

    for (int x = 0; x < GRID_SIZE; x++) {
      for (int y = 0; y < GRID_SIZE; y++) {
        map[x][y] = std::to_string(number).c_str()[0];
        number += 1;
      }
    }
  }

  void tictacToeMap() {
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (int x = 0; x < GRID_SIZE; x++) {
      for (int y = 0; y < GRID_SIZE; y++) {
        std::printf(" %c ", map[x][y]);
      }
      std::cout << std::endl;
    }
  }

  TicTacToe() {
    generateGrid();

    while (true) {
      champion();
      tictacToeMap();
      playgame();
      computers_turn();
    }
  }
};

int main() {
  TicTacToe ticTacToe;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: it is an unusual choice to execute all of a class's logic in a constructor.

Comment: In `computers…turn()` the type of `’0’` is `char`; the cast isn’t needed.

Comment: In `computers_turn()` don’t add 1 when you calculate `choice`. With the addition, `choice` can be 9, and when that happens, `row` will be 3, which is out of bounds. Array indices start at 0, and valid values here are 0, 1, and 2.

Comment: Thanks. My focus isn't mainly on the `computers_turn()` function because I still need to understand why it only shows a winner with "123". And without adding 1 to `choice` the program runs infinitely when all spots are taken.

Comment: Start working on testing functions, not the whole program. If you test the whole program, who knows how many bugs you have to sort out. If you fix a bug and still have more bugs, how do you know if the fix you made actually fixed anything? The program still doesn't work. The solution to that problem is to test with more granularity. If you give a function a set of inputs and you know what output you should get and you don't get it, one or more bug's are in that function and you can narrow the testing down further.

Comment: `possible_moves[i]` probably should use some other index, since `i` changing from 0 to 7, but `possible_moves` length is 3. Also, `entered_num - '1'` seems invalid, since `entered_num` is integer, not char.

Comment: @winstonmcnair -- if your code ever calls `computers_turn()` that index out of bounds can cause all sorts of problems. You need to fix it. And if your loop runs forever you've got another bug that you have to fix; creating an invalid index is not an appropriate solution.

Comment: I still havent figured out this bug yet, if anyone could help I would greatly appreciate it.